# If there is a element with specific tag name in php

Tags: php, xml

How can I know if there is a specific element with a specific tag name in php like below.

```
<?php 
  $element = getElementById("test");
  
  if ($element) {
    if there's an element
  } else {
    If not
  }
?>
```

Comment: Check the (enabled by default) [DOM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php).

Comment: Or SimpleXML https://www.php.net/manual/de/intro.simplexml.php

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` is a DOM method. It i available in PHP (on `DOMNode` objects). However it will return the element with a specific ID. This is not the tag name.

Xpath expressions can return values like this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML('<foo/>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('count(//foo) > 0'),
    $xpath->evaluate('count(//bar) > 0'),
);
```